# Sending select back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send a listbox  back to my controller from my view. I dynamically add items to it with a text box and button, and I want to be able to send all of these items back to my view in some kind of array. How would I go about doing this?

I had the following modelcode:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BasicIdentificationIndex(MyObject returndata, List<int> ints)
```

And then some input boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="ints" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="ints" value="8" />
```

**This code works and is returned to my controller(not null).**

**EDIT:**
 My issue is that I cannot get a select list to post back to my controller. I would like to send the following back to my controller:

```
 <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
  <option value="String1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="String2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="String3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="String4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

How would I go about doing this so that I can send a list of all the options( String1,String2,etc.) back to my controller? I have tried the following:

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult BasicIdentificationIndex(BasicIdentificationModel returndata,ICollection<String> AerialItems)
```

**Model:**

```
 public String AerialItems { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
 <select name="AerialItems" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
      <option value="5">Item 5</option>
      <option  value="6">Item 6</option>
      <option  value="7">Item 7</option>
    </select>
```

But The item returned back to the controller is always null.

Comment: What do you mean "properly returned to my controller"?  Was the ints parameter populated?  Does your `returndata` object also have an `ints` property that it might have gone to?

Comment: Properly as in not null. ints was indeed populated with the above code. If I place ints inside of returndata it is null, so I was just passing it as a second parameter instead of trying to figure out why it wont bind inside my object.

Comment: As long as the property in MyObject class is a `public List<int> Ints {get;set;}` then it *should* work. I don't think you need to, but *might* need to add in the default constructor of MyObject `Ints = new List<int>();` so that it is nonnull, but I don't remember for sure off top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just model bind back to a collection of ints...

I'm somewhat confused because this seemed to be copied from Haack's blog post on the subject... What you have listed should work, but if it's not could you include the rest of your code?

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough with my question. I updated it to be more clear at what I am trying to do. I was providing that as an example of how I was returning a list(which was from Haacks blog).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I need to use Javascript to select all the items in the list. This will post them all back in the collection.

Comment: If you always need the contents of the list to be POSTed, perhaps it's more useful to include them as hidden elements on your form. If the user must be able to deselect them, pre-select them in HTML (`selected="selected"`), not JavaScript.

Comment: Except the user can dynamically add to this list is the issue.

Comment: That should not be an issue, but if it works for you this way, go ahead.